# Transition max-height of div in relation to its max-width

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm pretty new to HTML, CSS and JS and right know I do a project for school.
So I have a timeline with years on it and everytime you click on the year a box expands with information in it. My problem now is that it always expand to its max-width but I want that the div is in a specific ratio. (tried aspect-ratio but didnt work)

Here is the following code

JS:

```js
$('.box2').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    
    function toggleActive() {
        $('.bigbox2').toggleClass('bigbox2').children('.content');  
    }

    $this.click(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('bigbox2') ) { 
            toggleActive();       
        }
        $this.toggleClass('bigbox2').children('.content');
    }) 
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #222;
    font-family: Impact;
}

.row2 {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: left;
    gap: 50px;
    position:absolute; top:10px;left:5px;
}

.box2 {
    position: relative; left: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    max-height: 25px;
    max-width: 55px;
    transition-duration: 200ms;
    transition-delay: 1ms;
    transition: max-width 0.5s ease 0s, max-height 0.5s ease 0s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.box2.bigbox2 {
    max-width: 700px;
    max-height: 1000px;

}

.box2 h2 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="right"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
<div class="row2">
        <div class="box2">
            <h2 class="title">2010</h2>
            <div class="content">
                <div>
                    <p>sjdfhasjdfsjkfhs dsdfh asjkdfhasjkdf hsajkdfhasdkjfhaskjfd hasjfd hasjfkhaslkdfjashkdjfhasfkjh sdjkf 
                        hasjkfhsajkfhsakfhasjkdfhasjkdfasjkfahsfjk asj hsaj hasdj fhasjkdf hasjk hfsakjfhasklfhaslfkjashdfjksadhfjsahfjsjkfafhsdfjkalsfh 
                        as sajfsjk</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So here is an example and I want like that it uses more height than width, but its using always so whole width.

Thanks already!!

Comment: So what you want is for it to settle at a given aspect ratio except when there is too much  text at which point the width is frozen and the  aspect ratio will become smaller than the given one. Is that right?

Comment: Well kind of. I want that the box is always as big as it needs to be to fit the whole text/images etc. But lets say the max-width and height is 1000px each and now when you click the box it opens at lets say: width 1000px and height 200px to fit the whole text in it. But I want that its uses for example width 600 px and height 300 px to fit everything. But everytime it behaves like that it first uses all of the max-width and then the rest of the height that its need to fit everything.

Comment: Could you say what the aspect ratio is that you want? In the question you say that you want it to use more height than width, but in your comment you have an example width of 600px and height of 300px - ie an aspect ratio of 2 / 1

Comment: I dont know yet, I would try different ones, but I'm thinking of something like 3/2.